# AlertView defined outside ViewController

Tags: iphone, class, uialertview

For easier code reading I decided to create AlertView as new object.
I created class AlertViews as subclass of NSObject.
I created 2 UIAlertView - one with single text Field and other as plain UIAlertView. 
To test it, I wanted to input text in UIAlertView click OK and see NSLog.

AlertViews.h

```
@interface AlertViews: NSobject 
{ 
   UIAlertView *addSomethingAlertView;
   UIAlertView * showSomethingAV; 
}


@property (nonatomic, retain) UIAlertView *addSomethingAlertView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIAlertView *showSomethingAV;

-(void)InitializeAddSomethingAlertView;
-(void)InitializeShowSomethingAV;
```

AlertViews.m

```
@implementation 

@synthesize addSomethingAlertView = _addSomethingAlertView;
@synthesize showSomethingAV = _showSomethingAV;

-(void)initializeAddSomethingAlertView {

    addSomethingAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Something" 
    message:@"something" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitle:@"OK", nil];

    addsomethingAlertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
    [[addSomethingAlertView textFieldAtIndex:0] setDelegate: self];
    [[addSomethingAlertView textFieldAtIndex:0] setKeyboardType: UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad];
    [[addSomethingAlertView textFieldAtIndex:0] becomeFirstResponder];

    [addSomethingAlertView show]; }

-(void)InitializeShowSomethingAV {

    showSomethingAV = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"show" message:@"show"
    delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitle:@"show", nil];

    [showSomethingAV show];


@end
```

ViewController.h

```
#import"AlertViews.h"

@interface ViewController: UIViewController <UIAlertViewDelegate> { 

 AlertViews *newAlert;
 AlertViews *showAlert; 
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) AlertViews *newAlert;
@property (nonatomic, retain) AlertViews *newAlert;

-(IBAction)adding:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)showing:(id)sender;
```

ViewController.m

```
@implementation
@synthesize newAlert = _newAlert;
@synthesize showAlert = _showAlert;

-(IBAction)adding:(id)sender {

    [self.newAlert = [[AlertViews alloc] init];
    [self.newAlert initializeAddSomethingAlertView];
}

-(IBAction)showing:(id)sender {

    [self.showAlert = [[AlertViews alloc] init];
    [self.showAlert initializeshowSomethingAV];

@end
```

I tried to implement this code in ViewController.m

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex 
{
    if (addsomethingAlertView) {if (buttonIndex == 1) { NSLog(@"adding"); }
    if (showSomethingAV) {if (buttonIndex == 1) {NSLog(@"showing"); }
}
```

However, I do not get any LOG.

Also, how can I use text entered in AlertView Text Field?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPOATE - I have figured out.

AlertViews.h

```
#import"ViewController.h"


@interface AlertViews: NSobject 
{ 
UIAlertView *addSomethingAlertView;
UITextField *addSomethingTF;
}


@property (nonatomic, retain) UIAlertView *addSomethingAlertView;
 @property (nonatomic, strong) UITextField *addSomethingTF;

-(void)InitializeAddSomethingAlertView;
```

AlertViews.m

```
@implementation 

@synthesize addSomethingAlertView = _addSomethingAlertView;
@synthesize showSomethingAV = _showSomethingAV;
@synthesize addSomething;


-(void)initializeAddSomethingAlertView {

addSomethingAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Something" 
message:@"something" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitle:@"OK", nil];

addsomethingAlertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
[[addSomethingAlertView textFieldAtIndex:0] setDelegate: self];
[[addSomethingAlertView textFieldAtIndex:0] setKeyboardType: UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad];
[[addSomethingAlertView textFieldAtIndex:0] becomeFirstResponder];

[addSomethingAlertView show]; }
```

ViewController.h

```
#import"AlertViews.h"

@interface ViewController: UIViewController <UIAlertViewDelegate> { 

 AlertViews *newAlert;
 UILabel *testLabel;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) AlertViews *newAlert;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel *testLabel;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *passString;

-(IBAction)adding:(id)sender;
```

ViewController.m

```
@implementation
@synthesize newAlert = _newAlert;
@synthesize showAlert = _showAlert;
@synthesize testLabel;
@synthesize passString;

-(IBAction)adding:(id)sender {

    [self.newAlert = [[AlertViews alloc] init];
    [self.newAlert initializeAddSomethingAlertView];
}

 -(IBAction)showing:(id)sender {

  [self.showAlert = [[AlertViews alloc] init];
    [self.showAlert initializeshowSomethingAV];

 @end
```

in AlertViews.m I added following code:

```
 -(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:
 (NSInteger)buttonIndex { if(addSomethingAlertView) { if(buttonIndex == 1) NSLog(@"testing success");


addSomething = [addSomethingAlertView textFieldAtIndex:0];
addSomething.text =[addSomethingAlertView textFieldAtIndex:0].text;




ViewController * vc = [[MainScreenViewController alloc] init];
vc.passString = addSomething.text;


NSLog(@"%@", grab);

}
```

Then in ViewController.m add this:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

testLabel.text = passString; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether you are able to get it work after implementing like below

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex == 0){
      //cancel button clicked. 
    }
    else{
      //For getting the text entered in alertview text field, you need to do like this
      UITextField* yourTxt= [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];
      NSString* txtContent= yourTxt.text;

    }
}
```

Hope it helps..

Comment: Thanks for help.
however, I can't use [alertView TextFieldAtIndex:0] in ViewController.m
xcode only allows it in AlertViews.m
that is the problem.

Comment: If you want your alertview's delegate methods to be called in viewcontroller.m, then you should set the delegate of alertview to viewcontroller's instance. Now you are setting delegate of both alertviews to AlertViews instance.

Comment: Thanks again.
Will this do the trick - in View Did Load:
ViewController *instanceVC = [[ViewController alloc] init];
self.delegate = instanceVC?
and then in AlerView delegate: self or instanceVC?

Comment: You can do it in two ways either set the delegate of actual UIAlertView to your viewcontroller instance or you can write a custom delegate method in your AlertViews class and make the ViewController as its delegate and call the delegate function when UIAlertView's button is clicked. This is the right way to do when you are creating reusable code.